# FTP alternative over HTTP

Tags: untagged

Some customers can't access my FTP because of their internal rules.

I need to set up a replacement of FTP using the HTTP protocol. I'd like to use an application running on an Apache server, able to easily allow the upload/download for the clients, and having some (even minimal) user management (so that such account can access such folder but not such other).

Ease of use is most needed for the customers.

The server is a Windows2003, with Apache 2. Any kind of scripting language is ok, but the application has to run in any standard web-browser.

Do you know of any application of this kind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/tour) - Simple PHP file manager

Answer (score 5):

Webdav will help you out. I would only run it over https

apache has a module for it

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html

Combined with Accessrules in Apache it should do what you want. A Client ist built into all major OSes

Answer (score 1):

Webdav requires a webdav client so not ideal. There are lots of scripts available for transfering / managing files over HTTP using just a browser as a client - but we'd need to know what OS / webserver and scripting languages are in scope to be able to recommend anything.

But why not solve the problem the right way and use [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)?

C.

Comment: Actually what is needed is a very easy interface for the customers. Anything involving comand line and not running in the browser would be worsening the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with WebDAV. There isn't really a [client software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV#Implementations) problem since most OSs of the last 10 years or so have supported it out of the box, though admittedly it's a bit rubbish in Windows. You can just mount a WebDAV volume as a drive.